# Problems with jquery offset in function scrollTo(id)

Tags: jquery, html, css, offset, scrollto

I am working on this site: [Website](http://mopra.dk/projects/MT)

This is a one page site, where I use scrollTo(id) see the code here:

```
function scrollTo(id) { 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - 50}, 1000);
}
```

The problem is, when you try an press a link when you are at the top of the homepage, the offset doesn't work and puts you almost below the section(page) you asked for. 
But if you scroll to the bottom of the page, and press a link, the offset works like a charm, and it puts you right at the top of every section you ask for.

You may look into my source code, I have a js.js file that should show all the functions I am using, maybe there is some other error I haven't noticed. 
really need your help :) ! hope you can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should always include all code that could cause your problem in your question so that otherusers that have the same problem could find the answer (even if your webpage goes offline)

Comment: remember your selector. try `{scrollTop: $('#' + id).o`

Comment: Okay i will remember :) 
and thanks for your answer, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks it's because of your menu.

When you're at the top of the page, your menu has a **static position**, witch also means that the height of the menu is added to the count of pixels for the browser to scroll to.

But when the browser has scrolled down to that position, the menu changes to a **fixed position**, witch then means that the height of the menu is subtracted from the top offset of the element that you want to scroll to.

In terms of code I would do simply add this little piece of CSS to the body.

```
body.tiny { padding-top: 60px; }
```

Assuming that the 60 pixels is the height of the menu. And when the menu changes to the fixed position the height will then be added to the bodys padding, pushing the content down as it was before.

This way you will also have a more smooth scroll when the menu changes it's position to fixed and reverse.